# Hide div if under ordered list with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to hide a div that displays comment info if the comment is a child.

In the code below I am trying to make it so if **"ol"** has class of **"children"** then the div inside with the id **"info"** will be hidden.

Also open to other ways of hiding the div if the the comment is a child.

```
<ol class="children">
  <li class="comment byuser comment-author-1 bypostauthor odd alt depth-2" id="comment-325" itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <article id="comment-325" class="comment row">
      <header class="comment-author vcard col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <section class="comment-content comment col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <div class="comment-meta"></div>
          <div itemprop="reviewBody">
            <div class='edit-comment-admin-links-no-icon ' id='edit-comment-user-link-325' style='background:none'>
              <div style='display:none'>
                <p>asdsadasdsadasasdasdas
                  <div id="info" class="cio-display cio-display-0">
                    <div class="cio-display-start-new-row"></div>
                    <div class="cio-label cio-label-service-provided">Service Inquired About:</div>
                    <div class="cio-field cio-field-service-provided">Buy/Sell Commercial</div>
                    <div class="cio-display-start-new-row"></div>
                    <div class="cio-label cio-label-deal-completed">Deal Completed?</div>
                    <div class="cio-field cio-field-deal-completed">Yes</div>
                    <div class="cio-display-start-new-row"></div>
                    <div class="cio-label cio-label-date-of-service">Date Of Service:</div>
                    <div class="cio-field cio-field-date-of-service">2015</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </header>
    </article>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Your `<li>` tag lacks a closing one.

Comment: There are several elements not closed here.

Comment: please fix the problems in the code ... this is not clear

Comment: Ok, why is everyone assuming this question requires a jQuery based answer? Why not do it via CSS? And, shouldn't jQuery based answers also advise on the special wrapping jQuery functions should have in WordPress? And maybe provide an example of how they should be enqueued? You all seem to assume this has to be done on some event, but I don't understand why are you making that assumption... What am I missing here?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu One of the two answers has a CSS solution, but that's assuming the user wants static code which may not be the case. They included the **`jquery`** and **`css`** tags, which means they are looking for a answer using either ways. Also SO isn't a tutorial, the OP at the minimum should know how to use either own environment and tags. For example whenever I give a jQuery answer I should not be mentioning that you need to wrap it in `document.ready` every time in case the DOM doesn't load.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek at the time I asked there was a second jQuery answer to this question. Got it. Based on tags. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the unfinished code. I copied the snippets of code I believed would be needed to help solve the issue and forgot include the closing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('ol.children #info').hide();`

Comment: Thank you, both this and ochiboy's comment below were exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the code you posted, this is the CSS code that you need:

```
ol.children #info {
    display: none;
}
```

However, assuming you have more than one of these comments, I have to add the following note:

> **Passing the same `id` to more than one element in your page is not a good idea.** `Id`s should be unique identifiers of HTML elements. You should use a `class` for your purpose.

Now, assuming your `to-be-hidden` elements will always be wrapped in elements with `itemprop="reviewBody"`, this is what you should use to hide them on ordered lists of comment that have the class `children`:

```
ol.children [itemprop="reviewBody"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's the "cleaned up" version of your code:

```html
<ol class="children">
  <li class="comment byuser comment-author-1 bypostauthor odd alt depth-2" id="comment-325" itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <article id="comment-325" class="comment row">
      <header class="comment-author vcard col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <section class="comment-content comment col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <div class="comment-meta"></div>
          <div itemprop="reviewBody">
            <div class='edit-comment-admin-links-no-icon ' id='edit-comment-user-link-325' style='background:none'>
              <div class="cio-display cio-display-0">
                <div class="cio-display-start-new-row"></div>
                <div class="cio-label cio-label-service-provided">Service Inquired About:</div>
                <div class="cio-field cio-field-service-provided">Buy/Sell Commercial</div>
                <div class="cio-display-start-new-row"></div>
                <div class="cio-label cio-label-deal-completed">Deal Completed?</div>
                <div class="cio-field cio-field-deal-completed">Yes</div>
                <div class="cio-display-start-new-row"></div>
                <div class="cio-label cio-label-date-of-service">Date Of Service:</div>
                <div class="cio-field cio-field-date-of-service">2015</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </header>
    </article>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Please note that the above code will hide the review body section of all the comments in your list if the list has the class `children`, including the top level ones. If an ordered list has even one children, it will probably have the class `children` added to it by WordPress.

If you only want to hide the review body section on level 2 comments (or higher) but keep them visible on level 1 comments, and assuming these level 1 comments have the added class of `level-1` (I'm guessing, since you didn't show us a level 1 comment) , this is the CSS you should use:

```
ol.children>li:not(.level-1) [itemprop="reviewBody"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Expounding from Kyle Emmanuel's answer, try to use this jQuery selector

```
$('ol.children div[id="info"]').hide();
```

Use the div[id="info"] selector if you're looking for **divs with info as id**. The #info selector will only return the first DOM element with info as ID, which should be fine anyway since you should only alot unique IDs to your elements.